# Storing a value to the second dimension

Tags: java

I am working on a project in java and I was wondering how I can store a value to the second array container

I have

```
int[][] figure = new int[4][6];
```

I have the following for loop

```
public void ask(){
                for(int i =0;i<Division;i++){
                        System.out.println("Enter sale for division " + i );
                        for(int j =0; j<4;j++){
                                System.out.println("For quarter " + j);
                                int input = keyboard.nextInt();

                            }
                    }


            }
```

How can I set input equal to the second array container [][]<--

Comment: its array of arrays so you store array to first and integer to second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2D array is an array of arrays, therefore you can:

Add values to 2D arrays with double for-loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
        array[i][j] = yourValue;
    }
}
```

Or do `array[index][index] = yourValue`.

Example:

Say I want to add a value to the first index of the first array in a 2D array of type `int`. 
I would do: 
`array[0][0] = 56`.

Then, to access a value from the array, I would do:
`int value = array[0][0]`